# How to take off paper glued to concrete with elmer's school glue

Tags: adhesive

How can I take off paper that was glued to concrete wall using elmer's school glue?

Comment: If it is actually *school* glue, which is water soluble, it should easily lift as described in the answers. Otherwise there is usually a plasticizer in it that makes it a good bit more water resistant. You may need a scrub brush to remove residue.

Comment: it is school glue. I will be trying removing the papers tomorrow. the thing I am worried about is that I can't apply the spray directly to the glue, since the glue was used to stick paper on concrete, and I need to remove the paper.

Comment: Warm (or even hot) water sprayed onto the paper will quickly wet through the paper and get to work at the glue below. If the paper has some type of plastic or other coating the warm water will make it easier to rip the paper off where you can the spray the glue.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using 409 without any dilution with warm water. I had glued some flyers onto concrete and needed to remove then. The glue was put on the borders of the flyer. I used a knife to scrape off the paper after soaking it with 409. It mostly worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A low cost general purpose spray bottle purchased at a hardware store...

[image]

Filled with a mixture of 75% / 25% Hot water and Windex...

[image]  [image]

Works surprisingly well to soften and aid in removal of paper and water based glues. Spray application permits just the right amount of moisture to be applied to the wall without large amounts of excess to run off make a mess.

Comment: In the past I have also used another liquid cleaner called "409" for this.

Comment: Were the pictures really necessary?

Comment: @ScottSEA - Was you comment necessary?  No!  If you do not like the pictures just scroll beyond them.

Comment: @MichaelKaras You're absolutely right; I apologize.  Yesterday was a bitchy day - I'm sorry I took it out on your post.

Answer (score 2):

Elmer's glue is water soluble. Just soak it with warm water and let it sit for 10 minutes. If that fails a power washer certainly do it.